# How can I find files with more than one line in them with a given name?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

**Question:** How can I get all the files with name "interesting-file.txt" that have more than one line in them?

**Background research:**

- I can find the files easly with `find . -name "interesting-file.txt"`
- I believe I need to use some form of `wc -l` to get their line
  number.
- I assume I would use `awk '$1 > 1'` to find those files with
  more than one line.

But I'm having problems putting it all together.

I've tried a few variations of

```
find . -name "interesting-file.txt" | awk '{print wc -l $0}'
```

with no success. I haven't started on the "greater than one" other than to look for the related command.

I'm on OSX, using the standard terminal.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would go for something like this:

```
find . -name "interesting-file.txt" -exec awk 'END { if (NR > 1) print FILENAME }' {} \;
```

All the files that are found are passed to awk, which prints the name if the number of lines `NR` is greater than 1.

With GNU awk you can take advantage of the `ENDFILE` block and use `{} +` to minimise the number of invocations of awk:

```
find . -name "interesting-file.txt" -exec awk 'ENDFILE { if (FNR > 1) print FILENAME }' {} +
```